# Subset a dataframe by row that contain a specific string anywhere inside the dataframe words

Tags: r

How could I subset a dataframe by a string that could be found anywhere in its columns? For example
"ol" exists only in the third row so that would give us only that row as result.

```
col1<-c("sd fgg","df dfg","fgh gdfg")
col2<-c("sd fgg","df dgfg","fgh gdfg")
col3<-c("sd fggg","dfg dfgg","fgghol gdfg")
df<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using R base

```
> df[unlist(sapply(df, function (x) grep("ol", x))),  ]
      col1     col2        col3
3 fgh gdfg fgh gdfg fgghol gdfg
```

A dplyr approach

```
df %>% 
  slice(.,
  rowwise(.) %>% 
  grep("ol", .) )
      col1     col2        col3
1 fgh gdfg fgh gdfg fgghol gdfg
```